Sci-fi streaming series where a mother hides a portal from her daughter
I watched either the first few episodes or the first season of this series within the last four years. It may have been cancelled or, like many series, delayed by COVID and the writers' strike.
In the opening episode the setting was desert-like, maybe Chile or the American Southwest. A mother and teen daughter live alone in a stone house. Their native language may be Spanish or an indigenous dialect of the Americas. The daughter is about to be sent away to school, I think.
However, the mother behaves strangely and being a curious teen, the girl follows her one day. On the property, in an outbuilding across from the main house is a small private chapel. On this day that the girl follows her mother, she discovers a secret door in the chapel.
A passage leads down some stairs to a hidden room. Inside there is a portal to another place. I cannot recall if it leads to different times, or locations or alternate realities. But apparently, her mother is the guardian of this portal and there are many other such portals, all with their own guardians. The guardianship is handed down from parent to child through many generations. It is the family's ancestral obligation to guard these portals.
At first there is some disagreement between the mother and daughter about this guardianship, but, in the end, the daughter decides that she wants to learn and become the next guardian of her mother's portal. That's all I can recall.
Does anybody know which series this is?

Tried to improve your title. Please write titles that behave like Google search terms. "Title of recent scifi streaming show" is not good or descriptive. "Recent" is a term that will age badly, too. Consider this site is a repository of questions and answers...

I remember seeing this. It was either Amz or NF.

Almost certainly Night Sky, a single season show that streamed on Amazon Prime in 2022. It was relatively well reviewed, but not popular enough to be renewed.
Wikipedia gives a plot summary:

An elderly couple living in the Midwestern United States discover under their land lies a device that can teleport them to a chamber that looks out onto the barren landscape and star-filled sky of another world.

The storyline with the mother and daughter was not the headline story, and was far enough removed to make it hard to recall that it was the same series at first, however a review of the second episode gives the link:

The episode, titled La Capilla, which means chapel in Spanish, takes
viewers to a llama farm in South America, introducing a single mother,
Stella.
While the storyline appeared random and confusing, it did not take
long to figure out that it had a connection to the alien portal in
Farnsworth, Illinois. Viewers later learned that Stella is the
guardian of her own teleportation device. But hers is hidden under the
church on their ranch, with an alarm system and cameras unlike the one
the Yorks have.


It's a shame this one wasn't renewed,  because I really liked it.

Agree - was looking forward to seeing where it went next.

Reminds me of Gravity Falls.

@Spencer Same here -- but when I just watched the first episode again, I realized again how slow it is. I mean, who wants to watch elderly couples on the sofa and visits to demented people in the old folks home, except elderly couples, perhaps? They changed pace a lot versus the end of the season, in what appears to me an almost desperate attempt to create more action and more revelations and cliffhangers to make enough people ask for a second season.  Perhaps the original design was to attract an older audience, but that didn't work so well.
